# Counting the Number of XPath Ancestors

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a different element that appears at different hierarchies in the xml tree. Take for example I have the `heading` element that can be in a `section` element or outside. I am trying to determine if this is the child of root and branch appropriately. I have the following xml and `xsl:when` clause but it doesn't work. For the element containing "Heading 1" it is getting passed to the otherwise. Why is this not working?

So for the xml here:

```
<root>
    <heading>Heading 1</heading>
    <section>
        <heading>Heading 2</heading>
    </section>
</root>
```

with the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="heading">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(ancestor::*)=1">
            ..do something..
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            ..do something else..
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<root/>` => `</root>`, and then [it works here](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/LlZpoE)

Comment: First, awesome website. I will definitely use that a lot in the future. But that is confusing to me, because I am tracing through the XSLT calls and using identical syntax and it is not working the same. Thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: Maybe adding the particular language / library you use to the tags on the answer might help finding out what kind of bugs/quircks are present there. And XsltCake is indeed fine, [thank Josh Comley](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116307/358679), he made it ;)